# switch from one fragment to another in main activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Example of what i'm trying to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhp10.png

I'm stuck on the part where i need to switch to createUserFragment from defaultFragment

i attached this to my button, but nothing happens when i press it, not sure what's wrong there

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    lateinit var navController: NavController


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        
        navController = findNavController(R.id.hostFragment)


        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph,drawer_layout)

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController,drawer_layout)

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigation_drawer,navController)

    }


}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,appBarConfiguration)
    }
```

**defaultFragment**

```
class defaultFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: defaultFragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = defaultFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return (binding.root)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

       

        binding.createNewBlankFAB.setOnClickListener{
            val transaction = (activity as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.defaultFragment, createUserFragment())
            transaction.disallowAddToBackStack()
            transaction.commit()
        }
    }

}
```

My questions are:
1)How can i fix my thing?
2)Will it work properly? I.e no memory leaks or some other funky stuff
3)Do i have to use another fragment for data input or maybe there's another way?

**UPDATE**
I stil have no idea how this works, but apparently i was replacing wrong fragment, i switched this R.id.defaultFragment in transaction.replace to R.id.hostFragment from which, i assume, all other fragments spawn, but now it just spawn on top of my existing fragment and the drawer button doesn't change its state, i guess i have to either do all of this differently or somehow pass to the drawer navigation information that current fragment was changed?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code here. We will need a more complete example. Where do you have this code? What class and method is it in? Please [edit] your question to show this **in code**, not in words. What is `binding`? Please show its declaration. Again, show code in context.

Comment: Updated question with code examples

Comment: Also, i have somewhat unrelated question, but how do i learn all of this stuff? Like what should i google in order to understand how fragments work? Or do i just try to build something while making a ton of errors and then just google each error one by one while trying to understand how something works?

Comment: I still don't see anything wrong. I suggest adding breakpoints and using the Android Studio debugger to see if you can get any clues to what is going on. Set breakpoints in `onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated()` and in the onClickListener.

Comment: For learning about fragments, head over to https://d.android.com. Google has a lot of great intro documentation there under Guides.

Comment: Or even just google "android fragments" and you'll get a lot of info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how we navigate within fragments in Navigation component library . We use navigate to then id of the destination Fragment which is defined in navgraph

```
binding.createNewBlankFAB.setOnClickListener{
        
    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.createUserFragment);
        }
```

Comment: This worked as expected, fragment changed and state of the Drawer Navigation UP button changed as well, still have no idea how all of this works, but huge thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to call "transaction.add" instead of "replace" since you are calling your fragment from an activity. Replace is called when you call a fragment from another fragment, I believe.

Comment: You might not be wrong about using `add()` instead of `replace()`. However, your reasons are not correct. Call `add()` when you are adding the first fragment. Call `replace()` when replacing an existing fragment with a different one.